# Programming Microsoft Emotion Api

Tags: azure-cognitive-services

I  want to use the Microsoft Emotion API but program it to detect an emotion it currently does not. Is it possible to do this?

Comment: Could you provide an example of your input and output?

Comment: The Microsoft Emotion API currently allows images to be processed of humans and determines their emotion based on their facial features but only checks for certain emotion. Happy, sad, angry etc. I was wondering if i could program it to process an image showing an emotion it currently does not output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The API to which you refer does not allow for customization.